# Delete empty folders algorithm

Tags: java, android, file, directory

I'm staring an android app for organize and clean my phone, and the first thing I'm starting to do is an "Empty Folders Cleaner", I thought it would be easy, and actually its easy, but I want go an step further...

Ccleaner, by example, only search for empty folders, that means if there is a folder with only an empty folder inside or so, you will need to use it 2 times, because the folder containing the empty folder will be empty after the clean, with my code I check if a folder only has empty folders inside, and it works for simple cases, like a folder with two empty folders inside, but when its more deep, it doesn't work as it should.

I want to know if a folder is empty and if a folder is safe to delete because it only has empty folders.

If I have a folder with a folder inside the output is this one:

```
Empty Folder: /storage/emulated/0/Folder1/Folder2
Folder safe to remove (only empty folders inside):/storage/emulated/0/Folder1
```

But with 3...

```
Empty Folder: /storage/emulated/0/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3
Folder safe to remove (only empty folders inside): /storage/emulated/0/Folder1/Folder2
```

Ignores the first one(`Folder1`)

Here is the method:

```
private void getAllEmptyFoldersOfDir(File directory) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "Folder: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
    int emptyFoldersCount = 0;
    final File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file != null) {
                if (file.getName().equals("Android") && file.isDirectory()) {
                    //We need to exclude this folder
                    continue;
                }
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    if (file.listFiles().length > 0) {
                        getAllEmptyFoldersOfDir(file);
                        continue;
                    }
                    emptyFoldersCount++;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Empty Folder: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        if (files.length == emptyFoldersCount)
            Log.d(TAG, "Folder safe to remove (only empty folders inside): " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated, and my English is not good so any edit is appreciated too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
boolean getAllEmptyFoldersOfDir(File current){
    if(current.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = current.listFiles();
        if(files.length == 0){ //There is no file in this folder - safe to delete
            System.out.println("Safe to delete - empty folder: " + current.getAbsolutePath());
            return true;
        } else {
            int totalFolderCount = 0;
            int emptyFolderCount = 0;
            for(File f : files){
                if(f.isDirectory()){
                    totalFolderCount++;
                    if(getAllEmptyFoldersOfDir(f)){ //safe to delete
                        emptyFolderCount++;
                    }   
                }

            }
            if(totalFolderCount == files.length && emptyFolderCount == totalFolderCount){ //only if all folders are safe to delete then this folder is also safe to delete
                System.out.println("Safe to delete - all subfolders are empty: " + current.getAbsolutePath());
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Whenever a folder is safe to delete, this method returns true. So whenever you do the recursive call, First all subfolders are scanned and validated that they are empty. Only if all the subfolders are empty (`emptyFolderCount == totalFolderCount`), the folder itself is safe to delete.

Comment: Thanks, but, 1, it doesn't work (it says all the folders are safe to delete), and 2, I want to know if a folder is empty and if a folder is safe to delete because it only has empty folders, I'll update my question.

Comment: can we achieve " from which folder it is safe to delete " in this method ? for example if I give you path of my directory then by scanning once method could decide if which all folder we can easily delete and which all can't be deleted

Comment: Ah, made a minor mistake, had to do an extra check to see if the folder might contain files aswell as folders. Edited the answer. This method outputs all folders which are safe to delete, which was the question that was asked here right?

Comment: @Nick ten Veen Thanks, it works now, but I forgot something in the question (already edited), I need to know which ones are just empty and which ones are safe to delete because his content is just empty folders (and ignore that subfolders), because I want the user to have the option to pick which folders delete, but, maybe with this code I can do it, gimme a day or so, if I can implement it, I'll accept it.

Comment: @JonathanHernández Edited one more time, now you can recognize when either a folder is empty or all subfolders in that folder are empty

Comment: @Nick ten Veen Thanks, it works as I need (I still need to add things but this answers the question), I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Addtionally to Nick ten Veen answer,
here is the code, how to delete the files using his method:

```
private void deleteEmptyFolders(File pathToClear){
    File file = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for(File f : files){
        if(f.isDirectory())
            if(getAllEmptyFoldersOfDir(f))
                if(f.delete())
                    Log.w("DELETED FOLDER (EMPTY)", f.getPath());

    }
}
```